# Import cert into keystore for Wildfly 9.2 (Error-keystore doesn't contain any key)

Tags: ssl, java, certificate, keystore

I have a p7b cert and I import into IIS and export into 3 .cer file as below.

1. root.cer
2. intermediate.cer
3. servercertificate.cer

then I use following commands to insert all 3 cer into my keystore successfully.

keytool -import -alias root -keystore  test.keystore -trustcacert -file root.cer

then I run my wildfly and the error "keystore does not contain any key" but when i list out the keystore, it has all the 3 keys inside. I'm not sure why it doesn't work and hope someone can enlighten me on this.

Answer (score 1):

A Java keystore can contain (at least) two different kinds of entries:

- a 'trustedCertEntry' entry that contains a certificate
- a 'privateKeyEntry' that contains a privatekey AND certificate chain

You created the first kind by importing lone certificates; look at the display from `keytool -list` and these entries will be labelled `trustedCertEntry`. **An SSL/TLS server requires a privatekey AND certificate chain, in a `privateKeyEntry`.**

I don't know ISS, but if you mean you generated the key and CSR in IIS, IIS normally uses the Windows keystore for some system account; I don't recall which but it should be obvious in the config somewhere. You need to run MMC+CertMgr for that account, locate the correct entry (which has a yellow key on the left side of the cert icon), and export it with 'Yes export the private key' in format 'PKCS#12 (PFX)' 'include ... path' to a file. In many cases Java/JCE can use a PKCS12 file directly as a keystore (instead of JKS) but if you need or prefer to convert to JKS use `keytool -importkeystore` (not `-importcert`).

See also near-dupe [JBoss Https configuration with CER/P7b certificate fails](https://serverfault.com/questions/858102/jboss-https-configuration-with-cer-p7b-certificate-fails)